# Why selenium chrome driver run in the background (headless mode)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have one application where I am using selenium chrome driver
Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" version="2.46.0"
When I run it from Visual Studio or from .exe file it is Console Application project
I can see chrome windows but when I schedule task from Windows Task Scheduler to run same .exe file I can not see windows. I can only see in task manger than Chrome windows working in so call headless mode.
Do any one know how to force driver to work in "normal" mode
something like option --disable-headless

Answer (score 0):

In my situation I have used "Run only when user is logged on"
[image]